# Need to create list using list value which are present in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
prod_sheet:
    Product ID
0   Prod1   00P000000000101
1   Prod2   00P000000000105
2   Prod3   00P000000000109
3   Prod4   00P000000000119
4   Prod5   00P000000000120

L=[Prod2,Prod4,Prod5]
```

Id for product which are present in list

```
needed_list=[00P000000000105,00P000000000119,00P000000000120]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if order is important list comprehension:

```
L=['Prod5','Prod4','Prod3']
s = prod_sheet.set_index('Product')['ID']

needed_list = [s[p] for p in L]
print (needed_list)
['00P000000000120', '00P000000000119', '00P000000000109']
```

If order is not important use:

```
needed_list = prod_sheet.loc[prod_sheet['Product'].isin(L), 'ID'].tolist()
print (needed_list)
'00P000000000109', '00P000000000119', '00P000000000120']
```

Comment: @RevatiCharhate - But it is not loop solution, remove loop here

Comment: @RevatiCharhate - Btw, is order important? e.g. `L=[Prod5,Prod4,Prod2]` ?

Comment: and then `needed_list=[00P000000000120,00P000000000119,00P000000000105]` ?